# SwiftUI - use an alert to change view

Tags: swift, swiftui

I use an alert when an user complete the registration, saying that, with a dismiss message saying "Ok", I want to change view when the user touch Ok, so I can go again to the main view.

I'm using `SwiftUI`, the alert comes when I press the registration button, and validate everything its ok.

```
Button(action: { 
   if registerController.validateRegistration() {
       registerController.registerUserInDB()
       showingRegistrationAlert.toggle()
   }}) {
       Text("Enviar registro")
   }
   .alert(isPresented: $showingRegistrationAlert) {
       Alert(title: Text("Se registro correctamente"), dismissButton: 
      .default(Text("Ok")) 
   }
```

Comment: Are you using Storyboard or SwiftUI? Please provide more details in your question, and possibly your code.

Comment: Yes, im using swiftui, ty.

Comment: No problem, if you are as well using NavigationLinks, I have posted a tested code version for you. Please let me know if it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and is not clear. So I am assuming you want to dismiss the view from detail view to main view.

If you are using `NavigationView` & `NavigationLink` you can dismiss the detail view  with using environment presentation mode.

Add `@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode` right above `body`.

and change your `Alert` to

```
.alert(isPresented: $showingRegistrationAlert) {
        Alert(title: Text("Se registro correctamente"), dismissButton: .default(Text("Ok"), action: {
            self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }))
         }
```

or if you are using `NavigationLink` with `isActive` binding you need to toggle that binding instead of `presentationMode`.

Answer (score 0):

Although that will be very dependent on how you want your app to behave, an easy approach would be to embed everything into a **NavigationView**, and activate a **NavigationLink** through a **@State var**, toggled by an **action** on the dismiss button.

You can take inspiration from the working and tested code below and adapt it to your needs:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var showingRegistrationAlert = false
    @State var navigateNext = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination:  DestinationVC(), isActive:$navigateNext) {
                    Text("")
                }
                
                
                Button(action: {
                    if registerController.validateRegistration() {
                        registerController.registerUserInDB()
                        showingRegistrationAlert.toggle()
                        
                    }
                })
                {
                    Text("Enviar registro")
                }
                .alert(isPresented: $showingRegistrationAlert) {
                    Alert(
                        title: Text("Se registro correctamente"),
                        dismissButton: Alert.Button.default(
                            Text("Ok"), action: {
                                navigateNext.toggle()
                            }
                        )
                    )
                }
                
                
                
            }
        }
        
    }
}

struct DestinationVC: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello!")
    }
}
```